# como puedo hacer un salto de linea en esta lista

Tags: python, lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta lista y cuando la ejecuto en CMD se me sale de la pantalla y tengo
que usar la barra de deslizamiento hacia la derecha para poder ver toda la lista.
Yo lo que quiero es que la lista no se pierda por la derecha de la pantalla y solamente tener que usar el scroll para bajar o subir y ver todas las peliculas que aparecen. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Gracias a todos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que es más sencillo de lo que parece, agrega un `\n` donde quieras hacer el salto de página, por ejemplo:

```
$peliculas80 = ["aullidos \n", ...]
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: No es una solución recomendable ni factible. Nunca sabes el espacio del que dispones ni el font a usar. No puedes precalcular donde se producirán los cortes. Además, puede que necesites los datos para más de un uso, y al agregar "\n" los corrompes.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el módulo [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) para lograr lo que buscas

```
import textwrap 
  
value = """Qui tempora non id aut corrupti reiciendis dolor quaerat. Non aut numquam ipsum qui dolorem aut maiores. Sed quia iure consequatur itaque. Nemo inventore molestiae et possimus velit explicabo aut.

Aut necessitatibus adipisci et nemo reiciendis. Unde excepturi voluptatum voluptatem quia. Amet corrupti ad rerum impedit aut possimus non. Odio iusto earum enim ullam. Fuga officiis dolor voluptas voluptas ut iusto repudiandae.

Voluptates officiis molestiae ut beatae qui. Nihil veritatis exercitationem libero. Nisi consequatur est ut maiores non architecto. Veniam mollitia qui fugit ut aliquid porro ducimus iusto. A dolorum sed et et provident.."""
  
# Wrap text. 
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=50) 
  
word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=value) 
  
# Print each line. 
for element in word_list: 
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que por defecto estas haciendo algo así:

```
    peliculas = ["pelicula 1","pelicula x",
            "pelicula y",
            "pelicula z",
            "pelicula muy grande titulo kilometrico..........",
            "cualquier pelicula",
            "vamos a imprimir las peliculas",
            "linea por linea"]
    
    print(peliculas)
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imprimir cada película linea por linea:

```
    peliculas = ["pelicula 1","pelicula x",
            "pelicula y",
            "pelicula z",
            "pelicula muy grande titulo kilometrico..........",
            "cualquier pelicula",
            "vamos a imprimir las peliculas",
            "linea por linea"]
    
    #print(peliculas)
    for pelicula in peliculas:
        print(pelicula)
```

Salida:

```
    (base) C:\python>python listasaltolinea.py
    pelicula 1
    pelicula x
    pelicula y
    pelicula z
    pelicula muy grande titulo kilometrico..........
    cualquier pelicula
    vamos a imprimir las peliculas
    linea por linea
    
    (base) C:\python>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El módulo `pprint` te permite fijar el ancho de impresión para estructuras de Python.

Para estos creas un objeto de impresión donde fijas el ancho de linea y también la separación con el margen izquierdo:

Se usa asi:

```
import pprint

lista=["una larga de listas de palabras en la primera linea de manera que todas juntas sobrepasen los limites de todo lo acordado",
       "de acuerdo con las ciertas representación olisoncritas que demuran la cúspide del sistema armilar sujeot a catalizasr"]

printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=5, width=40)
printer.pprint(lista)
```

produce:

```
[    'una larga de listas de palabras '
     'en la primera linea de manera '
     'que todas juntas sobrepasen los '
     'limites de todo lo acordado',
     'de acuerdo con las ciertas '
     'representación olisoncritas que '
     'demuran la cúspide del sistema '
     'armilar sujeot a catalizasr']
```

Hay 5 espacios de separación desde el borde izquierdo hasta el texto.